# CAST and REPLACE in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a column called Delivered_Cost in my table in BigQuery. It has "-" in it for rows with no cost. I'd like to replace that with 0s and then cast the column as float so that I can do some aggregations with it. However, when I use the code below, I run into issues. Some rows are changing to null even when they have values against them. How can I edit the code below so that I can replace and cast in the same query?

**SQL Code**

SELECT Delivered_Cost,

REPLACE (Consideration_Set, "0", "Undefined") as Final_Consideration_Set,
CAST(REPLACE(DELIVERED_COST, "-", "0") as float) as Final_Delivered,

FROM
  [table]

LIMIT 100;

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is the thousand separator (the comma) in your data. You can solve it by changing your query like this (removing comma):

```
SELECT
  delivered_cost, 
  REPLACE(Consideration_Set, '0', 'undefined') Final_Consideration_Set, 
  CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(DELIVERED_COST, ',',''), '-', '0') AS FLOAT) Final_Delivered
FROM [table]
```

Also, it is recommended to use Standard SQL in BigQuery rather than Legacy one. The Standard SQL version of your query is:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  delivered_cost, 
  REPLACE(Consideration_Set, '0', 'undefined') Final_Consideration_Set, 
  SAFE_CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(DELIVERED_COST, ',',''), '-', '0') AS FLOAT64) Final_Delivered
FROM `table`
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're using legacy SQL based on your table reference in brackets.
Go to Options and uncheck the option that says "Use Legacy SQL"

See the SQL I've included below. It works for me.

```
WITH table AS (
  SELECT
    '100.01' AS delivered_cost
    , 'News' AS consideration_set
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    '-' AS delivered_cost
    , '0' AS consideration_set
)
SELECT
  delivered_cost
  , REPLACE(consideration_set, '0', 'undefined') final_consideration_set
  , SAFE_CAST(REPLACE(delivered_cost, '-', '0') AS FLOAT64) final_delivered_cost
FROM table
```